# Adding Google Calendar Event Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-calendar-api

I am developing an app in Swift and am trying to add an event to Google Calendar. In my App Delegate, the user logs in, and I have:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = "498336876169-c0tedkl028ga401h2qj4g4gelnr68pen.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

In my view controller where I wish to insert the event, I have this method:

```
func addEventToGoogleCalendar(event: Event) {
        let calendarEvent = GTLRCalendar_Event()
        calendarEvent.summary = event.eventName
        calendarEvent.descriptionProperty = event.eventDescription
        let startDate = event.startTime
        let endDate = event.endTime
        calendarEvent.start = buildDate(date: startDate)
        calendarEvent.end = buildDate(date: endDate)
        let insertQuery = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert.query(withObject: calendarEvent, calendarId: "primary")
        service.executeQuery(insertQuery) { (ticket, object, error) in
                   if error == nil {
                       print("Event inserted")
                   } else {
                       print("error", error)
                   }
               }
    }
```

Upon testing this method, I was able to get the event information successfully, but when I try inserting the event, I get this error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=401 "Login Required" UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x2834787e0: {message:"Login Required" errors:[1] code:401}, NSLocalizedDescription=Login Required})
```

I'm not sure what exactly is causing the error, as the user signs in in the AppDelegate class. I tried to find solutions online, but noticed that there wasn't much documentation for using the GoogleCalendar API in Swift.

Comment: did you verify signin was successful?

Comment: The error is likely to tell you that the credentials on the request aren't correct (or are missing).

Comment: I verified signin was successful in another viewcontroller by using the sign function (conforming to the GIDSignInDelegate protocol). In my credentials, I also have an API key and a OAuth 2.0 Client ID.